# Change via SQL Query the description of a column

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

Is it possible to change with a SQL statement the description behind a column from a AccesDb?
To be more accurate: 
How can I insert a description for a column in an Access table using SQL in C#?

[image: The original table]

[image: Desc behind the column]

Comment: You mean like changing `Feldname` to `fieldname` in the result list?

Comment: No, The Data in the Beschreibungs-field (Beschreibung = Desc.)

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806362/how-to-insert-a-column-description-into-an-access-table The suggested solution uses VB, but I guess you will be able to port that to C#.

Comment: It's still not clear what the desired result should look like. What seems clear is that you have delimited data in one column - you could make things easier if you imported that data into a separate table with dedicated columns.

Comment: In Acces a column can have a description and i am trying to insert data into the description behind the column

Comment: But in VB its possible...

Comment: Yes it is. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806362/how-to-insert-a-column-description-into-an-access-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to set or change the description of a field using SQL commands.

An MS Access database contains pure database elements like *tables* and their *columns* (*fields*). Both have pure database-related *properties* like a *data type*, a *field size*, a *required* property, a *default value* setting or a *validation rule*. It should be possible to manage all these things using SQL.

But…

This is only a very small part of what an MS Access database can contain. Most of the objects in an Access database are built around these pure database things to display the data in the tables in a user-friendly user interface and let the user/developer create a custom front-end to either show and manage the data in a standard *data sheet* (which is a special kind of pre-defined Access *form*) or in more complex and user-defined *forms* and *reports*.

To support users in designing a custom user interface around the data, Microsoft has not only defined new object types like *forms* and *reports* but also added several properties to the objects on the data layer that are useful when displaying or editing the data in controls like *TextBox*, *ComboBox* etc. Some of these properties are *Input Mask*, *Format* or *Description*. They have nothing to do with the storage of the data but instead serve for something visual. These properties can’t be managed using SQL but can be defined and changed programmatically using a library like DAO where each *field* has a *properties collection* that does not only contain the original properties from the data layer but also the additional properties that were added to support the “visual” part of Microsoft Access.

**Added:**

An example in VBA could look something like this, it shouldn't be too difficult to translate it into C#:

```
Sub SetDescription(TableName As String, FieldName As String, Description As String)

    With CurrentDb
        With .TableDefs(TableName)
            With .Fields(FieldName)
                On Error GoTo Err_SetDescription
                .Properties("Description").Value = Description
            End With
        End With
    End With

Exit_SetDescription:
    Exit Sub

Err_SetDescription:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 3270
            With CurrentDb
                With .TableDefs(TableName)
                    With .Fields(FieldName)
                        .Properties.Append .CreateProperty("Description", dbText, Description)
                        Resume Next
                    End With
                End With
            End With
        Case Else
            MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation
            Resume Exit_SetDescription
    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks!, Can you give me maybe a example how to build it?

Comment: Just added an example in VBA, it should be possible to translate it into C#.

Comment: How did you save the changes to your Database?  
(sry im new to this technology)

Comment: The change isn't a change to data but a change to the table/field. it is saved the monent the value is set.

Answer (score -1):

The Answer:

```
    private string InsertDescription( string mdbFile )
{
    string log = null;
    DAO.Database db;
    DAO.DBEngine dbEn = new DAO.DBEngine();
    DAO.Recordset rs;

    string value = "Bi pe di Ba pe di Buuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu!!!!";
    string tabelName = "TAB";
    string columnName = "dbdb";

    try
    {
        db = dbEn.OpenDatabase(mdbFile, null, false, null);
        rs = db.OpenTable(tabelName, 0);
        rs.AddNew();

        db.TableDefs[tabelName].Fields[columnName].Properties["Description"].Value = value;
        rs.Update(1, false);
        rs.Close();

        log = "- Der Descriptionimport in die Datenbank war erfolgreich!";
    }

    catch( Exception ex )
    {
        log = "- Der Descriptionimport in die Datenbank war Nicht erfolgreich!" + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message;
    }

    return log;
}
```

Comment: You are adding a record to the table, you don't need a recordset to set the description. Also, if the description property hasn't been used yet, the property will not be there and you run into an exception. You obviously did not put any effort in translating into C# what I wrote in my answer and what you previously marked as solution. And still "the answer" to your question is: "No, it's not possible to change the description using SQL".