# DAO connecting to a database in c#

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, dao

I can't get a connection to my database, I only receive a compiler error that DAOWorkSpace is unassigned...
And the bigger problem is that I can't find any documentation for DAO in C#.

Yes i have to use DAO.

My code:

```
DAO.Database DAODataBase;
DAO.DBEngine DAODBEngine = new DAO.DBEngineClass();
DAO.Recordset DAOFoundCode;
DAO.Workspace DAOWorkSpace;

DAODataBase = DAOWorkSpace.OpenDatabase(mdbFile, null, null, ";pwd=");
```

I tried setting different arguments but I keep getting the same error.

I ran out of ideas.
Help is appreciated since I'm stuck here.

Comment: If you think you have to use DAO (which was outdated several years before C# was even released) I strongly suggest that it's more likely that you have *severely misunderstood* something. Can you add some explanation to your question of why you "have" to use DAO?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever The statement that DAO is outdated is a common misconception (several Microsoft support pages do state it, though). While JET DAO is indeed old and no longer being updated, and Microsoft intended to move to ADO in Access 2003, Microsoft instead switched to ACEDAO, which comes with the Access Database Engine since Access 2007, and is still being actively developed. For connecting to Access databases, it's sometimes a logical choice, mainly if you want to modify design. For any other database, it isn't.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51889936/change-via-sql-query-the-description-of-a-column/51893035?noredirect=1#comment90740651_51893035

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer:

```
        private string InsertDescription( string mdbFile )
    {
        string log = null;
        DAO.Database db;
        DAO.DBEngine dbEn = new DAO.DBEngine();
        DAO.Recordset rs;

        string value = "Bi pe di Ba pe di Buuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu!!!!";
        string tabelName = "AC_Tab";
        string columnName = "dbac3_ac_version_db";

        try
        {
            db = dbEn.OpenDatabase(mdbFile, null, false, null);
            rs = db.OpenTable(tabelName, 0);
            rs.AddNew();

            db.TableDefs[tabelName].Fields[columnName].Properties["Description"].Value = value;
            rs.Update(1, false);
            rs.Close();

            log = "- Der Descriptionimport in die Datenbank war erfolgreich!";
        }

        catch( Exception ex )
        {
            log = "- Der Descriptionimport in die Datenbank war Nicht erfolgreich!" + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message;
        }

        return log;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign the workspace first:

```
DAOWorkSpace = DAODBEngine.Workspaces[0]; //Default workspace
```

Also, don't set the properties in `OpenDatabase` to `Null`

```
DAODataBase = DAOWorkSpace.OpenDatabase(mdbFile, False, True, ";pwd="); //Shared mode, read-only
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer!
Thers still a error: Non-invocable member '_DBEngine.Workspaces' cannot be used like a method.

Comment: @m4gn1f1c4nt Sorry, my C# is rusty at best. Try the current edit

Comment: Thank you really much! 
And here we go with a new error (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Unrecognized database format 'C:\Users) message i can truely feel how much i love DAO

Comment: That's a weird one. I only have had that on corrupt/non-existent databases, or when trying to open .accdb files using Jet. Is it an mdb or an accdb? Are you sure it's a valid one (can you open it in Access)?

Comment: Its a mdb, yes it shoud be im creating it via OleDb & i can open it without any errors.
Is it possible that im not using the right .dll ?

Comment: That's a possibility. You can try printing `DBEngine.Version`. For MDB files, both ACEDAO (ACEDAO.dll) and DAO 3.6 (dao360.dll)  should do. I prefer using ACEDAO for everything, but some versions of DAO are shipped with Windows and won't need the Access Database Engine to be installed.

Comment: unfortunately not, Still thank you really much for your Help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178348/discussion-between-m4gn1f1c4nt-and-erik-von-asmuth).