# Programmatically add Column Comment to Microsoft Access-97 Database

Tags: vb6, ms-access-97

I have to programmatically update a large number of Access-97 databases with new tables and columns, and wish to fill in the description for each of the new column. To this end I have created code along the following lines:-

```
Dim MyTable  As TableDef
Dim NewField As Field

' Fill in MyTable...

Set NewField  = MyTable.CreateField("MyColumn")
NewField.Type = WantedType
NewField.Size = WantedSize

MyTable.Fields.Append NewField
```

but there is no property `NewField.Description`.

I try to create such a property thus:-

```
Call NewField.CreateProperty("Description", dbText, "My Comment", True)
```

but this does nothing.

Abandoning this approach I tried to create an SQL statement to execute to set the description, starting like this:-

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ALTER COLUMN MyColumn
```

but it transpires that Access 97 has no `ALTER COLUMN` ability. Neither is there any command `COMMENT ON COLUMN MyColumn` as there is on some database engines.

Is there anything else I can try to fill in the Description of a column from a program?

Comment: ADOX Perhaps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806362/how-to-insert-a-column-description-into-an-access-table

Comment: @AlexK.righto. I'll have a go with that. Thanks.